# How do I NOT use the placeholder/default/generic chart in MS-Access 2007 report design view?

Tags: ms-access, charts

After inserting a simple pie chart in the detail section of a new report, I get a generic chart, not based on my data (labels are East, West, and North).  I can format or alter the chart, and when I return to Report View or Print Preview, I see the chart with my data.

Interestingly, when I am in design view and double click the chart, a datasheet is presented that I not my data.  It is fake, default, generic, or placeholder data that has nothing to do with my database.

How do I get the chart, while in design view, to be drawn based on my data?

Comment: In design view, why do you care?

Comment: Using my own data provides the best representation of what the chart will actually look like.  I can select different chart or settings without having to switch to Report View.

Comment: In design view, why do you care?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with this a bit, I have found the solution.

When you add a new report to the database and then add a chart, it uses a generic placeholder chart in Design View.  Even if you save the report, it will continue to use the placeholder chart.

It is only after you close then reopen the database, does it use your actual data, but only after the second time you enter the Design View.

The steps to have a Report chart use your data in Design View are the following:

1. Create Report via Report Design
2. Add Chart
3. Save Report
4. Close Database
5. Open Database
6. Load Report in Design View
7. Go to Report View
8. Go To Design View

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a copy of access 2007 to hand but try this.

- Open up the query your report is
  based on and copy the datasheet into
  the clipboard
- Double click on your chart and that
  should bring up Microsoft Chart.
- In MS Chart bring up the datasheet,
  it should be showing the sample data
  of north south east west.
- Paste your data into that sheet, save
  and exit